# Configuring Spring Batch tasklet for Itemreader and ItemWriter using different data sources - connection reset error

Tags: java, spring

This is my configuration:

```
<batch:job id="myLoadJob">      
    <batch:step id="myLoadStep">            
      <batch:tasklet>
          <batch:chunk reader="myItemReader"
          writer="myItemWriter" commit-interval="1000">
      </batch:chunk>
      </batch:tasklet>      
    </batch:step>
</batch:job>
```

The problem is that after some commits the connection for the datasource for the ItemReader gets reset.

The solution I am exploring is to make the datasources XA aware.  From Spring docs I understand that Spring's PlatformTransactionManager which is the default will handle the transaction as global.  However after reading this https://spring.io/blog/2011/08/15/configuring-spring-and-jta-without-full-java-ee/ I am confused since it says I have to use this annotation:

tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager = “platformTransactionManagerReference”

And annotate the method as Transactional - example:
    @Transactional
    public void work() { 
        // the transaction will be rolled back if the 
        // method throws an Exception, otherwise committed
    }

I am looking for some clarity.

Thanks **@Kayaman** - hope below clarifications help

The exact events are as below: The reader does the read and populates the objects The writer startes writing in batches. After a certain number of writes an exception is thrown: 
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Connection reset

This connection pertains to that of the Reader. Hope this clarifies. Another post [Using 2 different datasources : Spring batch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16816116/using-2-different-datasources-spring-batch) describes a similar problem.  The answer recommended distributed transaction using XA aware datasource

Comment: You're not the only one looking for some clarity. What does "datasource for the ItemReader gets reset" mean? You don't need XA transactions. You only have one resource (the writer) that actually commits anything. The reader doesn't have anything to commit.

Comment: @Kayaman - Yes I realize that there is only one commit by the writer - but while the writer is running the Connection associated with the reader is idle and the database could be terminating the connection.  If we used XA, the thought is that the reader connection would be monitored by JTA arbitrator (for potential rollback) until the write completes successfully.  Does this make sense?

Comment: Eh, perhaps, but I'm not so convinced that you need an XA transaction for this. The batch framework already saves state in case the job needs to be restarted etc. Isn't that enough? Certainly if the read connection gets reset, there's no reason to rollback the writes. Just re-acquire the read connection and make sure you read from the proper position.

Comment: Thanks!  I will test your solution.  I would certainly like to avoid XA if I could.